# Angular Css not being executed from angular component css

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, angular9

My angular project is reading from a library that contains this code is a class:

```
class MyClass extends EventEmitter {

    constructor () {

      // add the element to the container
      this.loadingElement = document.createElement('div');
      this.loadingElement.className = "loading"
      this.loadingElement.innerText = 'Now Loading...';
    }

}
```

In my app.component.css I have this:

```
  #componentDivId .loading {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
  }
```

This css is in app.component.css

How can I change this so it reads the css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look into `::ng-deep` for overriding component styling. Also, may need to use `!important` in `css` file as and when required

[Here is a demo code to help you understand](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng-deep) how `::ng-deep` can be used to push styling to a child component.

Comment: Or, do this the correct way by creating a loader component and injecting it when you need it. Direct DOM updates to angular are an anti-pattern